# Get Celery logs in the same place as 'normal' Django logs and formatted by a Django formatter

Tags: django, logging, celery, supervisord

I try to find a way to gather the logs generatd from inside async functions called through Celery, inside the same handler that I use to log 'non-celery' django functions.

I have created a dummy function send a log each 3 seconds:

```
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from datetime import timedelta

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=3))
def every_3_seconds():
    logr.debug("Hello world: Running (debug) periodic task!")
    logr.info("Hello world: Running (info) periodic task!")
```

I have tried also something like this:

```
clogger = get_task_logger(__name__)  # Celery logger

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=3))
def every_3_seconds():
    clogger.debug("HelloCelery: Running (debug) periodic task!")
    clogger.info("HelloCelery: Running (info) periodic task!")
```

The log settings are (commented are my previous attempts):

```
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': 'HOPLA123 %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
        # 'django': {
        #     'handlers': ['console'],
        #     'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        # },
        # # Logger for the myappApp
        # # Use:  logr = logging.getLogger(__name__) in myappApp
        # #       logr.debug("....")
        # 'myappApp': {
        #     'handlers': ['console'],
        #     'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        #     'propagate': False, # To fix duplicate log issue. 
        # },
        # # Default Python Logger
        # 'root': {
        #     'handlers': ['console'],
        #     'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        # },
        # 'celery': {
        #     'handlers': ['console'],
        #     'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        #     'propagate': True,
        # },
    },
}
```

I have a supervisord config that outputs each of the logs in the suitable files:

```
[program:gunicorn_django]
environment=PYTHONPATH=/opt/myapp/myappServer/myappServer
command = /opt/myapp/venv/bin/gunicorn wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 90 --access-logfile /dev/stdout --error-logfile /dev/stderr
directory = /opt/myapp/myappServer
user = root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn.err

[program:redis]
command=redis-server
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/redis.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/redis.err

[program:django-celery]
command=/opt/myapp/venv/bin/python ./manage.py celery --app=myappServer.celeryapp:app worker -B --loglevel=INFO
directory=/opt/myapp/myappServer
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery.err
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
```

My *Hello world* logs inside a Celery function are logged into **/var/log/celery.err**, as specified in Celery doc:

> If no logfile is specified, stderr is used.

I would like to have them in the */var/log/gunicorn.log*, mainly to be formatted by the **verbose** formatter (in order to be correctly interpreted by a LogStash instance afterwards). Is there something wrong in the definitions of my loggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to myself:
The code from my questions actually works.

It seems that:

```
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

made the trick.